# Java Name Swapping

Tags: java

I think I have something very simple that i'm not totally understanding. I have some code which switches the names of two objects:

```
class Person {
    private String name;

    Person(String newName) {
        name = newName;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String val) {
        name = val;
    }

}

class Test {
    public static void swap(Person p1, Person p2) {

        System.out.println("Method Arguments: " + p1.getName() + ":"
                + p2.getName());

        String temp = p1.getName();
        p1.setName(p2.getName());
        p2.setName(temp);

        System.out.println("Method: " + p1.getName() + ":" + p2.getName());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Person person1 = new Person("John");
        Person person2 = new Person("Paul");
        System.out.println("Before: " + person1.getName() + ":"
                + person2.getName());// will output John : Paul
        swap(person2, person1);// will output John : Paul
        System.out.println("After: " + person1.getName() + ":"
                + person2.getName());// will output Paul : John
    }
}
```

This works as intended when using the arguments `swap(person1,person2); outputs Paul John`but shouldn't it work the opposite way as well? `swap(person2,person1);`still outputs Paul John wouldn't this be John Paul instead? Am I missing something fundamental or am I an idiot?

Comment: It will work for both cases.

Comment: Don't forget that if you swap them twice they return to original order.

Comment: There are a lot of places where you print the names. Why don't you show us the output of  your program, and which lines don't match your expectations.

Comment: The order in which you pass the 2 arguments to swap(..) will not matter. Your code is working as expected: https://ideone.com/ZkVBMa. But do note Elliott's comment that if you use swap() twice then the names will return to original order.

Comment: The confusion comes about because you are printing the names in your swap method. When you reverse the order of the parameters to `swap(p2, p1)`, your original person1 (in main) is now the stack variable `p2` and same for person 2 - thus the console output is inverted. However, when the final print from `main` is output, all is good in the world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think about it carefully you'll see that it's perfectly logical and correct that `swap(person1,person2);` gives exactly the same end result as `swap(person2,person1);`. In either case, regardless of the order, `person1` takes on the name of `person2` and `person2` takes on the name of `person1`.

Comment: Thank you for your help and understanding, my brain wasn't quite able to wrap around that concept until now.